# stl::iterators with raw pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

I want to use iterators with C++ arrays, but with raw pointers too.
I can do with a static vector:

```
#define SIZE 10
int vect[SIZE] = {0};
vect[3] = 5;
int* p = std::find(std::begin(vect), std::end(vect), 5);
bool success = p != std::end(vect);
```

How can be possible to do it with a raw pointer (maybe a heap allocated vector)?
Of course the compiler does not know the size of the data, so this code

```
int* pStart = vect;
std::find(std::begin(pStart), std::end(pStart), 5);
```

gives

```
error C2784: '_Ty *std::begin(_Ty (&)[_Size])' : 
could not deduce template argument for '_Ty (&)[_Size]' from 'int *'
```

Is it possible to make `begin()` and `end()` aware of it?

Comment: How can be possible to do _what_? What are you trying to accomplish? What is your goal?

Comment: Use a `std::array` instead, it has all of the features of a C-array but actually has the STL interface. And its iterators are implemented as pointers.

Comment: @rlbond Except in this case a plain array is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not possible to use `std::begin` and `std::end` on a pointer.  Unlike an array whose size is part of the type and therefor deducible a pointer does not hold the size of the thing it points to.  In your case with a pointer you would have to use

```
std::find(pStart, pStart + SIZE, 5);
```

The way to avoid this though is to use `std::vector` when you are not going to know what the szie will be at compile time.  It will manage the memory for you and provides `begin` and `end` member functions.

Comment: Using `std::vector` looks involving a copy of the data. Using `std::find(pStart, pStart + SIZE, 5);` is fine in this case.

Comment: @Stefano I'm saying if you are using a run time size you should be using a `std::vector` to start with.  If not then you can use a raw array or you can use a `std::array`.

Comment: I am using a C++ array because data are from a shared memory and the size of the array is dynamically allocated by a sort of shared memory manager.

Comment: @Stefano: In that case, the shared memory manager must also tell you the size. The start pointer and the start pointer + size **are** iterators. They can be used for everything which you would otherwise accomplish with `std::begin` and `std::end`, most notably all the standard algorithms in `<algorithm>`.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to make begin() and end() aware of it?

It's possible to implement `std::begin` for a pointer, but it is impossible to implement `std::end` (because as you say, the size is unknown), so it is a bit *pointless*.

However, you don't need either of those to use `std::find`:

```
int* p = std::find(pStart, pStart + SIZE, 5);
```

Comment: Except now you have a potential bug. Manual bounds like this are almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
std::begin(pStart), std::end(pStart)
```

you're trying to take the beginning and end of a pointer. Nope!

Instead, you meant:

```
std::begin(vect), std::end(vect)
```

This is the same whether you use an array, or a `std::array`, or a `std::vector`, or a particularly large elephant — to get the bounds of a container, you need the container.

Answer (score 2):

When I deal with *naked* arrays I rely on simple containers to make them compatible with C++'s general treatment of *ranges*.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>    // for std::unique_ptr
#include <algorithm> // for std::reverse
#include <numeric>   // for std::iota

template<typename T>

class range_view {

 public:

  range_view(T* data, std::size_t size)
      : m_data { data },
        m_size { size } { }

  const T* begin() const { return m_data; }
  const T* end() const { return m_data + m_size; }

  T* begin() { return m_data; }
  T* end() { return m_data + m_size; }

 private:

  T* m_data;
  std::size_t m_size;
};

int main() {

  // this is your actual data
  auto pdata = std::make_unique<int>(20);

  // this is a handle you use to work with your data
  auto data_view = range_view<int>(pdata.get(), 20);

  // for example, you can fill it with numbers 0, ... , N - 1
  std::iota(data_view.begin(), data_view.end(), 0);

  // it is now compatible with c++'s range-based operators
  std::cout << "my data...\n";
  for(auto && item : data_view) std::cout << item << " ";

  std::reverse(data_view.begin(), data_view.end());
  std::cout << "\nreversed...\n";
  for(auto && item : data_view) std::cout << item << " ";
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Compile and run

```
$ g++ example.cpp -std=c++14
$ ./a.out
my data...
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
reversed...
19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

You still have to worry about passing the correct dimension to the constructor, and it will fail miserably if the underlying pointer is deleted, but you had to worry about that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

While others answers already explains why you should revisit your design I want to state one option, that was not described earlier.

Your compiler diagnosis message almost clearly states that the compiler falls to deduce arguments and that arguments looks exactly like reference to С-style array.

Reference to C-style array doesn't decay to pointer, so you can pass reference to C-style array to std::begin and std::end in that particular case as an option:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

constexpr size_t SIZE = 10;

int main() {
    int vect[SIZE] = {0};
    vect[3] = 5;

    int (&ref_to_vect)[SIZE] = vect;    // declaring reference to C-array

        // and using reference to C-array which doesn't decay to pointer opposite to passing array "by value" semantics
    int* p = std::find(std::begin(ref_to_vect), std::end(ref_to_vect), 5);
    bool success = p != std::end(vect);
    std::cout << (success ? "Found 5" : "5 not found :(");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use iterators with C++ arrays, but with raw pointers too.

You got it backwards. Raw pointers **are** iterators. They iterate over arrays.

You can just use them for all the things you would otherwise accomplish with `std::begin` and `std::end`. Most notably, you can pass them to C++ standard algorithms in `<algorithm>`.

A pointer itself cannot be iterated. Iterators cannot be iterated.

> ```
> int* pStart = vect;
> std::find(std::begin(pStart), std::end(pStart), 5);
> ```

Very loosely speaking, a pointer is just a number. What is the "begin" and "end" of a number? This piece of code makes as little sense as the following:

```
int i = 123;
std::find(std::begin(i), std::end(i), 5); // error
```

> Is it possible to make `begin()` and `end()` aware of it?

A pointer *may* point to the beginning of some array. But that knowledge must be kept along with the pointer. You need to maintain a size or an end pointer along with a start pointer, and keep all that data together.

That's exactly what `std::array` and `std::vector` do for you.