# How to shift elements to end of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, shift

I have this array:

```
std::string langs[] = { "C++", "Ada", "Haskell", "Python", "Ada" };
```

I would like to write a function to shift K elements to the end for instance:

```
k="Ada";

{ "C++", "Haskell", "Python", "Ada", "Ada" };
```

I wrote this but its not working:

```
void moved(T e) 
{ 

    istd::vector<int> indexes;
        for (int i = 0; i < size_array; ++i)
        {
            if (array[i] == e)
            {
                indexes.push_back(i);
            }
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < (int)indexes.size(); ++j)
        {
            T temp=e;
            for (int i = indexes[j]; i < deleted_array_size-1; ++i)
            {
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
            deleted_array_size--;
            array[deleted_array_size - 1] = temp;
            
        }
}
```

How can I shift the elements?

Comment: "It's not working" is far less informative than you think. Does it compile, link, run, crash, or just not do what you expect? Does it shift some elements and not all? Please [edit] your question to be more informative.

Comment: `std::stable_partition(std::begin(langs), std::end(langs), [&](const std::string& elem) { return elem != k;} );`

Comment: [`remove_if` should do the job](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). And totally screw with the brain of whoever has to do the code maintenance.

Comment: @user4581301 `remove_if` would likely produce something like `{ "C++", "Haskell", "Python", "", "Ada" }`. It does move non-removed elements forward, but it does **not** move removed elements to the end; the tail of the sequence is left with unspecified contents - e.g. unmodified original values, or moved-from objects.

Comment: Good to know. I'll buffer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the order doesn't matter you can use [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition):

```
int main()
{
    std::string langs[] = { "C++", "Ada", "Haskell", "Python", "Ada" };
    std::partition(std::begin(langs), std::end(langs), [](auto& lang) {
        return lang != "Ada";
    });
 
    for (auto& str : langs) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

prints:

```
C++
Python
Haskell
Ada
Ada
```

If ordering *does* matter you can use [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Comment: Its working thanks:) and how can i use begin and end for ```string langs*```

Comment: `std::partition(langs, langs+n, ...` where `n` is the number of elements. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962903/stliterators-with-raw-pointers)